# Configuring Scvmm on a virtual machine with Windows server 2012 os

Tags: virtual-machine

I am trying to automate using MTM, and one of the requirements says that there should be an scvmm environment created to run the automated test cases.

Now, i am trying to install scvmm on a virtual machine created in hyper V. The os for the vm is windows server 2012. I was able to install scvmm successfully but when I am trying to create a Hyper V host and Clusters I am getting an error which says the operation Cannot be performed on the machine because the HyperV role is enabled. VMM automatically installs hyper V but requires a server restart to enable the role.

I tried to Enable the role in Server Manager but I am getting an error there too which says hyper v role cannot be enabled, hypervisor already installed.

Can somebody please tell me how to proceed .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it sounds like you might be trying to create a Hyper-V Host inside of a Hyper-V Guest.

You can certainly install SCVMM in a Hyper-V Virtual Machine. See "Test Lab Guides: System Center 2012 SP1 - Virtual Machine Manager" [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38837). "The guides describe how to deploy a VMM management server and a host in the test lab, and then tell how to use those servers to deploy multiple virtual machines that can work together".